# How to list really all objects of a nonexistant namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Okay, the title is quite mouthful. But it's actually describing the situation.

I deployed a service on GKE in namespace argo-events. Something was wrong with it so I tore it down:

```
kubectl delete namespace argo-events
```

Actually, that's already where the problems started (I suspect a connection to the problem described below) and I had to resort to a [hack](http://medium.com/@craignewtondev/how-to-fix-kubernetes-namespace-deleting-stuck-in-terminating-state-5ed75792647e) because argo-events got stuck in a Terminating state forever. But the result was as desired - namespace seemed to be gone together with all objects in it.

Because of problems with redeployment I inspected the GKE Object Browser (just looking around - cannot filter for argo-events namespace anymore as it is officially gone) where I stumbled upon two lingering objects in ns argo-events:

[image]

argo-events is not listed by `kubectl get namespaces`. Just confirming that.

And I can find those two objects if I look them up specifically:

```
$ kubectl get eventbus -n argo-events
NAME      AGE
default   17h

$ kubectl get eventsource -n argo-events
NAME                  AGE
pubsub-event-source   14h
```

But - I cannot find anything by asking for all objects:

```
$ kubectl get all -n argo-events
No resources found in argo-events namespace.
```

So my question is. How can I generically list all lingering objects in argo-events?

I'm asking because otherwise I'd have to inspect the entire Object Browser Tree to maybe find more objects (as I cannot select the namespace anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using command `$ kubectl get all` you will only print a few resources like:

- pod
- service
- daemonset
- deployment
- replicaset
- statefulset
- job
- cronjobs

It won't print all resources which can be found when you will use `$ kubectl api-resources`.

**Example**

When create `PV` from [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume) documentation it won't be listed in `$ kubectl get all` output, but it will be listed if you will specify this resource.

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/pods/storage/pv-volume.yaml
persistentvolume/task-pv-volume created
$ kubectl get pv
NAME             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
task-pv-volume   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Available           manual                  3m12s
$ kubectl get all
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.3.240.1   <none>        443/TCP   86m
$
```

If you would like to list all resources from specific `namespace` you should use command below:

```
kubectl -n argo-events api-resources --namespaced=true -o name | xargs --verbose -I {} kubectl -n argo-events get {} --show-kind --ignore-not-found
```

Above solution was presented in Github thread [kubectl get all does not list all resources in a namespace](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151). In this thread you might find some additional variations of above command.

In addition, you can also check [How to List all Resources in a Kubernetes Namespace](https://www.studytonight.com/post/how-to-list-all-resources-in-a-kubernetes-namespace) article. You can find there method to list resources using `function`.